# Is there a GUI difftool that does symlinks?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, symlink, utilities

Let's say I have some directories with symlinks in them.

```
.
├── dirA
│   ├── file013
│   └── file212
└── dirB
    ├── file013
    └── file212

2 directories, 4 files
```

The symlinks are pointing to directories with **lots** of files and directories that I don't care about, so I've used symlinks to isolate them.  I can edit them just fine, for example, and the changes are done on the actual files.

#### I want to compare say `A.file013` <> `B.file013`

Oh, I and I mostly work from the terminal, so looking for

#### `$ awesome_diff dirA/file013 dirB/file013` : diff 1 file pair

- opendiff/Filemerge does do this, actually. ✅  so does ksdiff/Kaleidoscope.

and

#### `$ awesome_diff dirA dirB` : diff at directory level.

- compare directory contents, drill down into directories, drill down into
  individual file diffs....

  - opendiff/Filemerge fails this ❌ as it will then consider only the symlinks' own pointers.  ksdiff/Kaleidoscope also ❌

(still appreciate GUI-only answers)

#### good:

- Gnu `diff` : does a fine job, but terminal-only.  Most GUI diff tools provide line by line copy functionality.

#### bad:

- Apple `Filemerge/opendiff` compares symlink file pointers, not file contents.  actually, if you launch Filemerge, the GUI, from the start it does work, but the command line opendiff calls the Filemerge incorrectly.
- `Kaleidoscope` - file type (symlink) not supported

#### unknown/install issues:

- `Kdiff3` - compares, but otherwise broken at 0.998 release, the menu doesn't work at all for example.
- `Meld` - haven't gotten it to work on macos yet.
- `Diffmerge` - haven't gotten it to work on macos yet.

**env:  Mojave**

Comment: I just tried with Filemerge. When selecting symlinked files in the Open Dialog, the tool follows the symlink and compares the files they point to.

Comment: Nice to know.  but that's pretty brutal in terms of workflow when you are in the terminal all the time like me.  Launch it, then pick left file, pick right file.  It does remember last working directory, but the other one is always going to be wrong.  Still, if you write it up (copy paste comment will do, definitely upvoting).  and editing my question to clarify.

Comment: It also works for `opendiff`, not sure why it doesn't seem to work in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Filemerge and `opendiff` work with symlinks, so

```
opendiff symlink-to-foo symlink-to-bar
```

will open Filemerge and compare `foo` vs `bar` .

Comment: ah, interesting.  `opendiff dirA dirB`, then look at folder contents and drill down into files doesn't work - once you pick your files they resolve to symlinks.  however, `opendiff dirA/file013 dirB/file013` does.

Comment: same behavior from ksdiff/Kaleidoscope.

Comment: let's see what else pops up, but if no else chimes in any better ideas, I can live with this.  I would really prefer the same behavior you get from comparing 2 directories with normal files, but, well, beggars can't be choosers.